# I am looking for a board like the Multiwii Crius SE. It is currently discontinued and I really need an alternative that supports Multiwii firmware

Tags: quadcopters, flight-controller, firmware

Here is a link to Multiwii and it's site --> http://www.multiwii.com/
Multiwii was really popular around 2011 to 2015. Ever since, their best board, the Crius SE, has been discontinued. I am really in need of a board that was made by them or can support their firmware linked here --> https://github.com/multiwii/multiwii-firmware

If you look at their config.h file, there is a list of boards the firmware supports. Now what makes this a challenge is that the board needs to support a quadcopter construction. It also needs to be AIO or all in one.[image: Part of the config file that has potential boards.]

I am very new to drones so I am not great with specs. If the community has any alternatives to the board or any other great boards in mind, that would be very helpful!

Comment: Multiwii was famously open source, as well as most of their board designs being so. It's likely you can get gerbers for a particular board (even maybe the crius) and have boards manufactured yourself

Comment: @BrydonGibson I actually recently got a gerber that I made and got 5 boards manufactured. Didn't turn out as planned. I really couldn't find Crius Gerbers. Do you know of a place where I could get crius gerbers?